# laravel admin login after, how can change to other page?

Tags: laravel, admin

laravel admin login after, how can change to other page?

when I using this address login

```
http://localhost/admin/auth/login
```

the default page is http://localhost/admin

how can change to http://localhost/admin/blog

blog

this is my code

```
Admin::routes();

Route::group([
    'prefix'        => config('admin.route.prefix'),
    'namespace'     => config('admin.route.namespace'),
    'middleware'    => config('admin.route.middleware'),
    'as'            => config('admin.route.prefix') . '.',
], function (Router $router) {

    //$router->get('/', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
    $router->get('/', 'BlogController@index')->name('index');
    //$router->resource('blog', BlogController::class);
    $router->resource('blog', 'BlogController');
});
```

Comment: how are you having the 'admin' login?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In LoginController, change `$redirectTo = '/admin/blog'`

Comment: protected $redirectTo = '/admin/blog';  this?

but still cant

Comment: yes. Check if '/admin/blog' route's function does some navigation to '/admin'.

Comment: how can check? because when I loggin, the default page still is /admin

Comment: use dd in the functions.

Comment: dd? sorry, I dont ur mean

Comment: when I using this address login

http://localhost/admin/auth/login
the default page is http://localhost/admin

how can change to http://localhost/admin/blog